# Why don't my CALayers animate? Instead they just instantly jump into place with the new values

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer, caanimation

I have a CALayer with a gradient color effect on it. I want to change the "locations" and "colors" value to change up the gradient. And I'm trying to animate it.

But with the following code it just instantly changes to the new values.

```
    let gradientDuration = 0.25

    let locationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
    locationAnimation.fromValue = lowerGradientView.layer.locations
    locationAnimation.toValue = newLocations

    let colorsAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
    colorsAnimation.fromValue = lowerGradientView.layer.colors
    colorsAnimation.toValue = newColors

    let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    animationGroup.duration = gradientDuration
    animationGroup.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    animationGroup.animations = [locationAnimation, colorsAnimation]

    lowerGradientView.layer.add(animationGroup, forKey: "locationAndColors")
    lowerGradientView.layer.locations = newLocations as [NSNumber]?
    lowerGradientView.layer.colors = newColors
```

What am I doing wrong to cause the layer not to animate the changes?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is these lines at the end:

```
lowerGradientView.layer.locations = newLocations as [NSNumber]?
lowerGradientView.layer.colors = newColors
```

They cancel the animation, in effect.